# VBA - File Dialog vs Grab Newest File in Directory?

Tags: vba

I currently provide a file dialog to permit a user to select the desired file from a pre-defined directory.  Works as expected; I am just looking to reduce steps/interaction.

The files are simple timestamped log files, many in the directory.  I do not know the actual filename, but I do know the desired file will always be the NEWEST file in that directory.

Is there a way to select the filename for the file with the newest date/time from a known directory?

- Thanks!

Comment: If there's a will, there's a way. Lookup how to get a file's creation date, and then iterate the folder, locate the youngest file, *and then still prompt the user for confirmation* - that way the user still gets a shot at locating the file themselves, and then when (not if; *when*) your assumption that "it will *always* be the newest file in that directory" is shattered, you won't have to rewrite anything.

Comment: As it stands your question has a yes/no answer if answered at face value.. which makes a rather boring Q/A (FWIW the answer is "yes"). If you meant to ask "how to grab the newest file in a given directory", then your question is either a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6656023/1188513), or simply *too broad*, for you're not providing your attempt at solving the problem, nor describing how that attempt isn't working.

Comment: @Mat, Yes I suppose I should have asked "HOW" to perform that task.  Looking at the link you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good approach here:

[finding latest file in a folder and opening it (vba access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490868/finding-latest-file-in-a-folder-and-opening-it-vba-access)

```
Function NewestFile()

Dim FileName As String
Dim MostRecentFile As String
Dim MostRecentDate As Date
Dim FileSpec As String

'Specify the file type, if any
 FileSpec = "*.*" 
'specify the directory
 Directory = "C:"
FileName = Dir(Directory & FileSpec)
If FileName <> "" Then
    MostRecentFile = FileName
    MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(Directory & FileName)
   Do While FileName <> ""
        If FileDateTime(Directory & FileName) > MostRecentDate Then
             MostRecentFile = FileName
             MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(Directory & FileName)
         End If
         FileName = Dir
    Loop
 End If

 NewestFile = MostRecentFile

 End Function
```

`
A few minor adjustments to suit my needs; works as desired.